# C/C++ problems on pointer de-referencing

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  float a = 12.01;
  int *b = (int *)&a;
  printf("%p\n%p\n%f\n",&a,b,*b);
  return 0; 
}
```

`b` contains the address of `a`, then while de-referencing `b`, it gives junk values ?

Please answer, I got the same issue while derived class pointer pointing to base class object.

Comment: imho: its not a good idea to cast a float (reference) into a int pointer.  `int *b = (int *)&((int)a);` could work, but everything inside me keeps screaming

Comment: What did you expect? You're trying to read a `float` as if it were an `int` (i.e. reinterpret the bit representation)...

Comment: Undefined behavior. While `float` can be casted to an `int`, this is only for the plain values and not for the pointers.

Comment: If you try to use generalized pointers use a `void *` pointer. However, don't try to read directly from a `void *`.

Comment: More undefined behaviour: you're passing a (supposed) `int` as a `printf` argument where `double` is expected.

Comment: Is this about C, or C++? They're different things, you know. There's no such thing as "C/C++".

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis looks more like C

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Oh, it looks like a lot of things..

Answer (score 2):

> `b` contains the address of `a`, then while de-referencing `b`, it gives junk values ?

First you use a dodgy cast to point to a `float` but pretend you're pointing to a different type `int`.

Then you read the value, giving undefined behaviour; typically, if both types are the same size, you'll get the bit pattern representing the floating point number, which will look like garbage.

Then you pass that dodgy `int` value as a `printf` argument matching the `%f` specifier, which expects `double`. That gives more undefined behaviour; most likely, it will interpret some random memory as a `double` value, giving complete garbage.

If you want to retrieve the expected floating-point value, then you'll need to cast back to the correct type: `*(float*)b`. If you want to convert the *value* to `int`, then convert that, not a pointer: `int b = (int)a;`. The cast here isn't strictly necessary, but some compilers may give a warning that the implicit conversion loses information.

> I got the same issue while derived class pointer pointing to base class object.

That's a different, but related, issue. Again, you're lying about what type the pointer points to, and you'll get undefined behaviour if you try to use that pointer to access the wrong object type.

Perhaps if you asked a more specific question about that situation, explaining why you think you need the dodgy cast, we could advise you on how to achieve what you want within the type system.

Answer (score -1):

Try this ...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 float a = 12.01;
 void *b = (int *)&a;
 printf("%p\n%p\n%f\n",&a,b,*(float *)b);
 return 0; 
}
```